# Design pattern for large scale gui

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns, user-interface

I'm new to complex gui applications. I know the `MVC`-pattern but I don't know how to apply them on large gui applications.

Let's take as example a large editor application. The editor has several menus and dialogs (page configuration, editor configuration, print dialog,...).

On university I learned to separate between user interface and business logic and communicate over an interface. In that example above the user interface is very large so that interface, call it `viewinterface`, is very large. All elements of the concrete `view` fire events which the corresponding application-controller handles.

I think for small guis this approach is possible but how to deal with large guis? Are the better patterns to solve this problem systematically?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "large scale" a bit more perhaps? Pin it down slightly.

Comment: I already described it a bit. I mean much menus, complex dialogs, table and so on.

Comment: @Razer Design patterns are abstract concepts that aren't really confined by the scale of the application. Of course scale does require several variations implementation wise, and in general larger scale demands a combination of patterns, but that doesn't mean that the concepts themselves vary. You need to be a lot more specific on what the actual problem is, we can't really guess what patterns may be more suitable based on vague descriptions like "menus, complex dialogs, table and so on". As is your question is [too open ended to be answerable](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution isn't simple and it does not consist out of some simple answer with some "design pattern".

What I would suggest you is to go step by step, depending on your platform and language apply some sort of MVC pattern, and also following common GoF design patterns for separating commands etc... If you didn't read GoF book, the editor app is the example of all the patterns in there.

As long you follow the single-responsibility principle (and other SOLID principles), your interfaces will not be huge and cluttered, but applying all these techniques requires experience, and practice ...